# What is the amalgamated free product of $\mathbb Z^2$ over $\mathbb Z$?

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, algebraic-topology, solution-verification, fundamental-groups

This is related to an algebraic topology question which uses Van Kampen theorem.

Let $X=A\cup B$ for $A,B$ open and path-connected subspaces of the ambient space.

Suppose that $\pi_1 (A)\cong \mathbb Z^2$ and $\pi_1 (B)\cong 1$.

Also we have that $A\cap B$ is nonempty and path-connected, and $\pi_1 (A\cap B)\cong \mathbb Z$.

Okay, so Van Kampen tell us that
\begin{equation*}
\pi_1 (X) \cong \pi_1 (A) \ast_{\pi_1 (A\cap B)} \pi_1 (B),
\end{equation*}
or the amalgamated free product of $\pi_1 (A)$ and $\pi_1(B)$ over $\pi_1 (A\cap B)$.

Switching to the notation of generators, I know that $\mathbb Z^2 = \langle a,b : ab=ba \rangle$ and also that $\mathbb Z = \langle c \rangle$.

Moreover, we will have induced homomorphisms $\phi_\ast : \pi_1 (A\cap B) \hookrightarrow \pi_1 (A)$ and $\psi_\ast : \pi_1 (A\cap B) \hookrightarrow \pi_1 (B)$ and in particular these will be inclusion, i.e., injective maps.

I know that since $B$ is simply connected, therefore $\psi_\ast (\alpha) = 1$ for any $\alpha \in \pi_1 (A\cap B)$, but I don't know what $\phi_\ast (\alpha)$ would be.

I considered $\phi_\ast,$ the inclusion from $\mathbb{Z}$ into $\mathbb Z^2$ but I'm not sure what this would look like, since elements of the latter are ordered pairs whereas $\mathbb Z$ is just single numbers. I believe once I figured out this step then I can get the necessary relations for the group presentation of $\pi_1 (X)$.

As an alternative application of V.K., I know we get
$$\pi_1 (X) \cong \left( \pi_1 (A) \ast \pi_1 (B) \right) / N,$$
where $N$ is the smallest normal subgroup of $\pi_1 (A) \ast \pi_1 (B)$ which contains all elements of the form $\phi_\ast (a) \psi_\ast (a)^{-1}$ for all $a\in \pi_1 (A\cap B)$, but once again I run into the issue of figuring out $\phi_\ast (a)$.

My next thought, does it help if I consider breaking up $\pi_1 (A)$ into not $\mathbb Z^2$ but just two individual copies of $\mathbb Z$, and apply V.K. in a different manner?

Comment: What you have makes no sense. If $\pi_1(A\cap B)=\mathbb{Z}$, and embeds into $\pi_1(B)$, then how can $\pi_1(B)$ be trivial?

Comment: Oh, duh. I'm not sure where I went wrong. The space in question is a torus with a closed disk glued inside of it. So I was thinking that $A$ is the torus, $B$ is the disk, and the intersection is homotopic to a circle.

Comment: I think your assumption that $\phi_*$ and $\psi_*$ are injective is wrong. The easiest counterexample is the map $i : S^1 \hookrightarrow D^2$. This is an injection, but the induced map $i_* : \pi_1(S^1) \cong \mathbb{Z} \to 0 \cong \pi_1(D^2)$ is not injective.

Comment: It's been a long time, but as I recall the SvK Theorem gives the pushout, which **if** the maps are injections gives the amalgamated free product, but if not then the construction is more complicated.